# Ext JS - What is the best way to clone to and from a store?

Tags: extjs, extjs5, extjs-stores

I have a permanent data store .
I want to clone the records to a temporary data store,make changes to the records and then copy the modified records back to the permanent store.

I created the temporary store like this:-

```
permanentStore.each(function (record) { 
    temporaryStore.add(record.copy());}
);
```

How do I copy back only the modified records ? 
Do I need to find the matching records using id for all the modified records or is there any other easy way?

```
permanentStore.findRecord('Id','temporaryStoreRecordId')
```

Is there any clean way of cloning so that the changes are applied to the permanent store automatically ?

Comment: First of all, its not a clone if the changes are automatically applied to the permanent one. So what exactly do u want? why do you need to find modified records from temp store if you are making a temp store only. You can directly replace your permanent store with the temp one which has modified records right? My suggestion would be you could use Ext.clone for that if what i am getting the requirements of yours are right. Otherwise please ellaborate properly

Comment: @Anindya: The approach you used is ok but instead you can use much cleaner approach by just cloning store as Harshit mentioned above.Now for copying modified records back you will need to iterate clone store and set modified records to each respective records in original store.Try this and reply if it works

Comment: What exactly do you need a temp store for, if the records should be edited in-place?

Comment: I see no need for a temporary duplicate store here. You can edit the records in the permanent store. There is a [reject method](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.data.Model.html#method-reject) if you want to undo unsaved record changes - Utilize this if your concern is preserving the original record. I can't think of another reason you might want to clone the entire store - it might help to know what your end goal is

Answer (score 1):

You can use `clone` method to clone all `records`.

`var clonerecord = Ext.clone(records);`

`temporaryStore.add(cloneRecord);`

`temporaryStore.getModifiedRecords();` to get modified records.

`temporaryStore.getNewRecords();` to get new records.

`temporaryStore.getRemovedRecords();` to get remove records.